# Find the lowest combination of XOR

Tags: math, optimization

Consider the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  time_t seed;
  time (&seed);

  srand (seed);

  int i, j, k, l;

  // init random values s1 .. s8

  int s[8];
  for (l = 0; l < 8; l++) s[l] = rand ();

  // zero result

  int r[16];
  for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) r[j] = 0;

  // do 100 random xor functions

  for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
  {
    // generates random function to show why CSE must be computed in runtime
    int steps[16];
    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) steps[j] = rand ();

    // _here_ is optimization possible
    // run function MANY times to show that optimization makes sense

    for (l = 0; l < 1000000; l++)
    {
      for (j = 0; j < 16; j++)
      {
        int tmp = 0;
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++) tmp ^= ((steps[j] >> k) & 1) ? s[k] : 0;

        r[j] += tmp;
      }
    }

    for (j = 0; j < 16; j++) printf ("%08x\n", r[j]);

    puts ("");
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Inside the code, the following unrolled function is executed many times in a loop:

```
r[ 0] += s01 ^ s03;
r[ 1] += s02 ^ s04;
r[ 2] += s03 ^ s05;
r[ 3] += s02;
r[ 4] += s03;
r[ 5] += s04 ^ s06;
r[ 6] += s03;
r[ 7] += s04;
r[ 8] += s02 ^ s04 ^ s05 ^ s07;
r[ 9] += s03 ^ s04 ^ s05 ^ s07;
r[10] += s04 ^ s05 ^ s06;
r[11] += s05 ^ s06 ^ s08;
r[12] += s03 ^ s06;
r[13] += s06;
r[14] += s02 ^ s03 ^ s04 ^ s05 ^ s06 ^ s07;
r[15] += s03 ^ s04 ^ s05 ^ s06;
```

Makes a total of **23 XOR**.

But the implementation is bad. An optimized version is this:

```
int s04___s05 = s04 ^ s05;
int s03___s06 = s03 ^ s06;
int s04___s05___s07 = s04___s05 ^ s07;
int s03___s04___s05___s06 = s03___s06 ^ s04___s05;

r[ 0] += s01 ^ s03;
r[ 1] += s02 ^ s04;
r[ 2] += s03 ^ s05;
r[ 3] += s02;
r[ 4] += s03;
r[ 5] += s04 ^ s06;
r[ 6] += s03;
r[ 7] += s04;
r[ 8] += s02 ^ s04___s05___s07;
r[ 9] += s03 ^ s04___s05___s07;
r[10] += s04___s05 ^ s06;
r[11] += s05 ^ s06 ^ s08;
r[12] += s03___s06;
r[13] += s06;
r[14] += s02 ^ s03___s04___s05___s06 ^ s07;
r[15] += s03___s04___s05___s06;
```

Makes a total of **15 XOR**.

I am searching for an algorithm that automates this step and finds a solution that uses **the lowest number of XOR**.

If there are multiple solutions find the one with the lowest number of storage for precomputation.

If there are still multiple solution it does not matter which to choose.

Some additional informations:

- In the real program the XOR's of the function can be random because they depend on user-input.
- There are always 16 steps done.
- The number of XOR per step can be between 0 and 7 XOR.
- The number of storage required for the precomputed values does not matter

I am a bit lost on how to write this.

Comment: What is the point of optimizing this? If it only occurs once on startup.

Comment: No the function is not. It is inside a loop which is executed many times.

Comment: I see, it read like it was only on startup.

Comment: thanks for the hint, i've updated the post to make that clear.

Comment: Do the numbers s01 to s08 change during the execution of the program? If not `s04___s05` etc can be calculated just once.

Comment: Yes you were right. Just saw that. I've edited the function a bit so that r cant be precomputed.

Comment: I think it is NP-Hard, it smells too similar to the "Minimum equivalent disjunctive normal form for a given truth table problem"... Though a reduction doesn't 'pop' to my head at the moment.

Comment: If input s1 to s8 is constant and r[] depends only on them, can't you pre-compute whole r[]?

Comment: No with each iteration of the function the result of the XOR's it added (+=) to each r[] element, not assigned.

Comment: @atz: You need to update your question to show how the RHS of each of the equations change. You stated in answer to weston's question that the values of s1 ... s8 do not change.  Since the RHS of your equaitons for r[i] are dependent only upon those s1 ... s8 values, there should be no problem with precomputing the parts which depend only upon s1 ... s8.  You have since stated that the RHS for each equation does change. This seems to be a contradiction which could be easily cleared up by better explaining the nature of the change on the RHS between successive iterations.

Comment: @andand OK, added an example program to show how its used. Hope that make things more clear

Answer (score 2):

We want to compute `r[i]`. It is equal to maximum 8 inputs XOR'ed between themselves.
Now, think about this: s8 ^ s6 ^ s5 ^ s4 ^ s3 ^ s2 ^ s1, like about a number 10111111.
1 if we use corresponding `s` in XORing, 0 if not.
We can pre-compute all possible 2^8 variations:

```
t[0] = 0       (00000000, nothing)
t[1] = s1      (00000001)
t[2] = s2      (00000010)
t[3] = s2 ^ s1 (00000011)
t[4] = s3      (00000100)
t[5] = s3 ^ s1 (00000101)
...
t[255] = s8 ^ s7 ^ s6 ^ s5 ^ s4 ^ s3 ^ s2 ^ s1 (11111111)
```

Then in loop if you want for example calculate:

```
r[0] = s1 ^ s3
```

s1 ^ s3 in our representation is 00000101 = 5, which gives us index to pre-computed lookup table:

```
r[0] = t[5]
```

That solves your problem without any XOR in loop.

Comment: I think this very nicely solves his problem for all his possible permutations of the function. Not that it's not going to give any performance boost (over the case specified) however as it now requires 16 array lookups, which, as they involve an add operation, will be as bad as 16 XORs. But is still great as there's no additional logic required in the loop +1

Comment: That is a neat Idea. It is not exactly what i was searching for, but maybe it is ok for what I am doing.

Comment: @weston since the specific combinations are known at compile time, there will be no addition at run time.

Comment: @phkahler An array lookup is an add in disguise. It takes the array's base pointer and adds an offset. `t[6]` is just `t + 6`

Comment: Don't XOR all 256 combinations, just pre-compute the right-hand side of your addition operations so the code becomes r[0] += xor_stuff[0]. The 16 values you're adding don't change so they can be computed just once.

Comment: @phkahler The OP was not very clear, but the right hand side changes WRT which sX values are XOR'd. The XORs he specified were just an example. So this answer provides a quick way to look up any given combination of XORs.

Comment: @weston I have added an example program. Hope that makes things more clear.

Answer (score 2):

Let's first search for an abstract problem definition: You have a bitvector type with a length of 8 bit, which represents a combination of your 8 input signals. For each signal, you have a bitvector value like `10000000` (first signal) or `00100000` (third signal). These values are given. You want to generate the following values (I left out the trivial ones):

```
r[0]  = 10100000
r[1]  = 01010000
r[2]  = 00101000
r[5]  = 00010100
r[8]  = 01011010
r[9]  = 00111010
r[10] = 00011100
r[11] = 00001101
r[12] = 00100100
r[14] = 01111110
r[15] = 00111100
```

We now want to search for the minimum of combinations (executions of `XOR`) to generate these values. This is an optimization problem. I won't do a complete proof for the lowest amount of `XOR` executions here, but this is what I get:

```
int i1 = s02 ^ s04; // 01010000 
int i2 = s03 ^ s05; // 00101000
int i3 = s04 ^ s06; // 00010100
int i4 = s05 ^ s07; // 00001010
int i5 = s03 ^ s06; // 00100100
int i6 = i1 ^ i4;   // 01011010
int i7 = i2 ^ i3;   // 00111100
int i8 = s06 ^ s07; // 00000110

r[0]  = s01 ^ s03;
r[1]  = i1;
r[2]  = i2;
r[5]  = i3;
r[8]  = i6;
r[9]  = i7 ^ i8;
r[10] = i3 ^ s05;
r[11] = i4 ^ i8 ^ s08;
r[12] = i5;
r[14] = i6 ^ i5;
r[15] = i7;
```

14 `XOR`s.

To formulate a general algorithm: You start with a Set `S={10000000, 01000000, ... , 00000001}`. You need a weighting function that tells you the value of your set. Define this as: The number of `XOR`s needed to calculate all goal values from values in `S` without storing additional temporary values **plus** the number of values in `S` **minus** 8 (initial values). The first part of the weighting function can be implemented with brute force (find all possible combinations for a goal value that use each value in `S` at most once, choose the one with the least `XOR` executions).

To optimize the value of your weighting function, you combine two values from `S` with `XOR` and add them to `S`, giving `S1`. Choose those two values which grant the lowest new value of the weighting function (again, this can be determined by brute force). S1 now has one more value (which will be a temporary value like the `i` values in my solution). To create this value, one `XOR` is needed (therefore, the weighting function counts the number of values in `S`).

Continue this step until you don't find any new value to add to `S` that reduces the value of the weighting function. The resulting set contains the initial values plus all temporary values you have to calculate. The steps you took will tell you how to calculate the immediate values.

This is a greedy algorithm. It doesn't necessarily find the minimum number of `XOR`s, but shows you an easy way to at least get a *good* solution. It might be that the algorithm actually always finds the best solution, but this would have to be proven. If you want to be absolutely sure, you can do a complete traversal of all possible steps that reduce the value of the weighting function, starting with the initial `S` values. This would be a tree traversal, and the tree will be finite - as the value cannot drop below 0 - so it's definitely solvable.

Comment: This inspired me :-) I will now try out something. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

What you've done here manually is actually a classic compiler optimization called [common subexpression elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_subexpression_elimination) (CSE).

Before doing it by hand or using a tool to do CSE on the source code, check the resulting assembly to see whether your compiler is already doing CSE for you. Chances are it is -- and note that the compiler is really the place where CSE should be done, since there is a tradeoff to be made: The more aggressively you do CSE, the more you reduce the amount of computation you need to do, but the more storage (i.e. registers or RAM) you need. Doing CSE too aggressively can actually hurt performance if it causes you to spill registers or increase your memory bandwidth -- the compiler will typically have the knowledge on how to perform this kind of tradeoff.

Comment: Thanks for telling me the name. It might help to find some additional infos on the web. The compiler can not optimize it since the function itself changes while the program is running. Thats why I have to implement it into the code.

Comment: @atz: Are you saying that not only the numbers in `s1`,...,`s8` change while the program is running but also the actual expressions in which they're involved? In other words, the code you're showing above is only illustrative and is not the actual code you're compiling?

Comment: Yes, exactly thats my problem. Sorry for not explaining it this way.